# Red5 server Integration with C application

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, rtmp, red5

I am newbie to Red5 server. I have a C command-line application which outputs RTMP stream to given ingestion point. Now I am writing a wrapper application to automate (on the fly) Red5 application creation/configuration and RTMP stream ingestion in a single command. Here are my query:

1. Once I create/Configure Red5 application do I need to restart Red5 server to publish streams or it will be published automatically??

More queries on the way. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explored further about Red5 and found that applications can be deployed without having to restart Red5 server. Here are the steps to do that:

1. Create/Configure Red5 application as per your requirement.
2. Create a war file out of your config directory.
3. place the generated war file under /webapps/

Red5 uses a War deployment Bean which can be identified as the warDeployService. This is a scheduler service with watches for new Red5 applications in the webapps directory. New applications must be deployed as .war files. When the warDeployService discovers a new .war file candidate it attempts to extract it automatically and install the Red5 application in less than 10 minutes.The warDeployService checks for new war files as defined by the bean descriptor(checkInterval).The service may fail if your .war file is not packed in appropriate structure.

Note: Packaging .war file of your application may not be same as “Export as War” feature in eclipse, due to difference in application structure.

The Red5 warDeployService bean can be found in the file /conf/red5-common.xml located in Conf directory as shown below.

```
<!-- War deployer -->
<bean id="warDeployService" class="org.red5.server.service.WarDeployer" init-method="init" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <property name="scheduler" ref="schedulingService"/>
    <property name="checkInterval" value="${war.deploy.server.check.interval}"/>
    <property name="deploymentDirectory" value="${red5.root}/webapps"/>
</bean>
```

War file polling time is 10 Mins(600000 in milliseconds) by default. It can be configured in /conf/red5.properties file.

```
war.deploy.server.check.interval=600000
```